# SQL: Finding duplicate values in a field, but using SubString()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, substring, inner-join, duplicates

Here's a question for all those SQL SERVER 2000 experts:

I have only 1 table... I can already find if any of the values in a certain field, also appears in another record.

> I.E.:   Does any record have
>   "ABCDEFGHI" in a field, and then
>   "ABCDEFGHI" again in that same
>   field... but in another record.

But I run into trouble when I try to use substrings.

> I.E.:   Does any record have "CDEF" in
>   a field, and then "DEFG" again in that
>   same field... but in another record.
>   (Edit: That would NOT be a match, of course.)

I'm trying to compare PART of 1 field, with PART of another.
Only compare characters 3-6 characters, with characters 4-7.
(I need to specify my own start-end ranges, for both fields.)
What the specific letters are... doesn't matter.   Just that they 'match'.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT t1.ID + ' + ' + t2.ID  
FROM InfoTable As t1         
INNER JOIN InfoTable AS t2     ON t1.ID = SUBSTRING(t2.ID, 3, 4)
```

(Edit:  I also need to NOT list any records that are just matching themselves.)

Comment: It's far from clear what you're trying to find here. Do you want all records that have "CDEF" anywhere in them, linked to all other records that have "DEFG" anywhere in them? Is it all records that have "CDEF" starting at position 3, linked to all other records that have "DEFG" starting at position 4? Is it all records that have characters 3 to 6 of a common string, linked to all other records that have characters 4 to 7 of the same common string? Something else?

Comment: Anywhere in them?  No, just the start/end substrings I specify.
Starting at position a, and b characters long...
Matching records that start at position c, and are d characters long.  (Of course, b and d would have to be the same for a match to occur.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

```
SELECT t1.ID + ' + ' + t2.ID  
FROM InfoTable As t1         
INNER JOIN InfoTable AS t2     ON SUBSTRING(t1.ID,3,6) = SUBSTRING(t2.ID, 4, 7)
```

Comment: I tried that, and it seems to return records that match themselves.  Is there a way to exclude those 'same record' matches?

Comment: add another condition to the ON clause...

and t1.id < t2.id

Comment: Simply add `AND T1.ID <> T2.ID` to the WHERE clause. That's assuming that ID is unique. It would probably be best if you gave a table definition, sample data, and expected results - that's always a good idea when posting SQL query questions.

Comment: Some great ideas.  Let me try them.  Are either of these "better":  "Add < to the ON clause"... or... "Add <> in the WHERE clause"?  (To avoid records matching themselves.)

Comment: @Helen: I think having it in the ON clause is better, because it makes it clear that you don't want to link to the same record. (Processing-wise, in this query it shouldn't make any difference.) Using `<>` would enable the same two records to appear twice with each other, if **both** SUBSTRING(t1.ID,3,6) = SUBSTRING(t2.ID, 4, 7) **and** SUBSTRING(t2.ID,3,6) = SUBSTRING(t1.ID, 4, 7) - on the other hand, if only the latter is true, then using `<` would mean that neither would appear. I suggest that `<>` is therefore better.